# Poll with multilingual choices in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-7, multilingual

I've installed the poll module in Drupal 7 and I want to have a multilingual poll, so that the choices could be in differents languages and sum the votes of the choices. I've found these posts:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66280/multi-language-poll-output

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51513/poll-in-two-languages

The problem is that I'm not able to develop the solution because I don't know where I have to apply the patch since i18n module in drupal 7 doesn't include the i18n_poll subfolder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the patch is the module itself. Use the following and you'll get ".info" and ".module" files (tested on my linux) :

```
patch < 1173130_i18n_poll_module_5.patch
```

Then enable the module. I don't know if it will solve your poll issue but it answers the main question at least.